# How do I select rows in an Sqlite table with a limit on the number of rows with a condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an Sqlite table (having > 25 million rows) that looks like this:

```
rowid   overall    text
-----   -------    ----
 1         5     'text1'
 2         4     'text2'
 3         2     'text3'
 4         1     'text4'
 5         3     'text5'
 6         5     'text6'
...       ...      ...
```

The `overall` column has values ranging from 1-5. Now I wish to select `overall` and `text` from this table limiting to 1 million rows, but ensuring that in my selection, 500,000 of the rows have an overall > 3, while the other 500,000 have an overall < 3. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make two queries, then [combine them](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT overall, text
               FROM MyTable
               WHERE overall > 3
               LIMIT 500000)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT overall, text
               FROM MyTable
               WHERE overall < 3
               LIMIT 500000);
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.